# Creating a catalogue template

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm making my first steps learning to code. I have been taking some courses on internet about css, html, javascript, php and mysql. Since some months ago I decided to continue learning while I experiment with wordpress.

As a beginner I always start watching templates, which I decompose to analize and then I see what can I do.

I'm looking for a template with a really basic structure. I would like to use my content as an ipad magazine does:

[image]

Do you have some suggestion about a template with a similar structure? Or at least fiddle that could give me a clue about how can I proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the Bootstrap Templates wich are pretty much easy to understand and learn from it.